# Eslint suddenly stopped working, React plugin

Tags: reactjs, eslint, lint

My eslint config stopped linting my code, it doesn't show errors or anything, I'm confused is there something wrong with my config? Do I need to add some configs for eslint:recommend for it to work? I just followed the [react plugin](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react) steps, I appreciate the answers.

```
 "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "indent": ["error", 2],
    "semi": ["error", "always"],
    "max-len": [2, { "code": 80, "tabWidth": 2, "ignoreUrls": true }],
    "react/jsx-max-props-per-line": ["error", { "maximum": { "single": 1, "multi": 2 } }],
    "react/jsx-first-prop-new-line":"always"
  },
    "plugins": [
      "react"
    ],
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem...
"react/jsx-first-prop-new-line":"always"

- the above line is expecting a number for it to work 0 1 2
  "react/jsx-first-prop-new-line": 2
- 2 Meaning "On" is the correct way to write it